# Adding vertical space between figure and numbering

Tags: floats, subfloats

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\makeatletter
\newbox\sf@box
\newenvironment{SubFloat}[2][]%
{\def\sf@one{#1}%
\def\sf@two{#2}%
\setbox\sf@box\hbox
\bgroup}%
{ \egroup
\ifx\@empty\sf@two\@empty\relax
\def\sf@two{\@empty}
\fi
\ifx\@empty\sf@one\@empty\relax
\subfloat[\sf@two]{\box\sf@box}%
\else
\subfloat[\sf@one][\sf@two]{\box\sf@box}%
\fi}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
% \captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty} % Removes a), b) labels
%
\begin{SubFloat}
{\label{fig:1} }
\includegraphics[width=0.42\textwidth]{fig.png}%
\end{SubFloat}
\vspace{1cm}
\qquad
\begin{SubFloat}
{\label{fig:2} }
\includegraphics[width=0.42\textwidth]{fig.png}%
\end{SubFloat}

\begin{SubFloat}
{\label{fig:3} }
\includegraphics[width=0.42\textwidth]{fig.png}%
\end{SubFloat}
\qquad
\begin{SubFloat}
{\label{fig:4} }
\includegraphics[width=0.42\textwidth]{fig.png}%
\end{SubFloat}

\caption{Caption blah blah.}
\label{figure-temp}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

which gives me this:

[image: output]

I need some way to add vertical space between the caption of each figure ("X AXIS") and the letter assigned to it (a, b, c, d) Not to the whole article, but to this figure in specific. Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `captionskip` key in the `figure` environment:

```
\begin{figure}[!htp]
\centering
\captionsetup[subfigure]{captionskip=20pt} % adjust the value
%
\begin{SubFloat}
...
\end{Subfloat}

\caption{Caption blah blah.}
\label{figure-temp}
\end{figure}
```

Using `[!ht]` with so large a float is a bound to troubles, better `[!htp]`.

Comment: Great, that did it! The `[!htp]` advice is duly noted. Thank you!